# IdentityServer3 integration with CAS (Central Authentication Service)

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, cas, identityserver3

I'm trying to implement a Single Sign-On solution for two applications that currently use different identity providers:

- **Application A** - Custom app, written in C#.NET, have full control over it and currently uses Asp.NET Membership
- **Application B** - Off the shelf software written in Java (Pentaho), control limited to configuration only, and currently uses CAS (but also supports Integrated Windows Authentication). It acts as a CAS client and I have limited control to the CAS server.

My initial idea was to use IdentityServer3 (OpenID Connect and OAuth2) as the single sign-on solution.

**Application A** would be fairly simple to convert, but I couldn't find any solution for integrating **Application B** (CAS client) with IdentityServer3 (or any other OpenID Connect and OAuth2 implementation).

I understand they are different protocols but I would like to know if:

- This is possible and how would it be implemented at high level considering I only have full access to **Application A** and the **IdentityServer3**? What would be the effort required?
- What are the alternative solutions?